# Any easy php script to sign and send transactions maybe run contract also

Tags: php

Thanks I have JavaScript version but not php version especially for sign and send transaction

Comment: Could you add more details about what you want to achieve specifically? You can find a PHP implementation [here](https://github.com/kesar/ethereum-php)

Comment: @PaulRBerg apparently, the code you are linking uses an Ethereum node, where you should unlock the account, not very secure, unless the node and php run on the same machine and communicate using loop back interface

Comment: better there is some easy php or js lib with examples